# Matlab (2008a-32bit) single precision bug

Tags: matlab

If I make a single precision operation with the values, it will give a result ending with 8:

```
>> single(single(6.500001e+02)*single(-64.1775131)*single(0.65)*single(2))
ans =   -5.4230008e+004
```

Then I make any operation using double precision, and the same operation as before, using  single precision, the result will be different from the first time I run it:

```
>> double(6.5000012e+02)*double(-64.1775131)*double(0.65)*double(2)
ans =   -5.423000858119204e+004

>> single(single(6.500001e+02)*single(-64.1775131)*single(0.65)*single(2))
ans =  -5.4230004e+004
```

This problem happens in Matlab 2008a 32 bits. This is not a problem in Matlab 2012b 64 bits.

Any thoughts on how to avoid this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this effect in MATLAB Version: 8.2.0.701 (R2013b).I get the second single result also the first time. Just for the record.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on MATLAB R2012a/32 bit(win32).

Comment: Also, check this, seems related: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/246425 You seem to have access to R2012b, why not use it?

Comment: I am no longer work on 2008a, but I think this version had an issue with single precision. Try working with another version.

Comment: My guess would be to ask on a Mathworks forum as Mathworks employees will be able to look into the actual code to determine if there is/was a bug.  It does seem like a bug and one that they fixed in a subsequent version. :-)

Comment: `6.5000012e+02 != 6.500001e+02`, even outside of floating point considerations. You have an extra digit in there that is easily enough to produce the change you see in your least significant digit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not test but, from what I could find on MATLAB Central, it seems to be a bug in the Global Workspace @versions R2008*. So, to avoid the problem:

- Don't execute code from Command Window;
- Stick to double precision, unless under severe memory constraints (it's even faster, because default type is double);
- Work in functions rather than scripts (apparently the function local Workspace is not affected by this bug)
- Use a R2009+ MATLAB release, which seems to have fixed the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using functions actually worked!